# GitHub: We haven’t found any dependents for this repository yet

Tags: github, open-source, bootstrap-styled

I have seen the feature that show what package depend on a repository.

[image]

I have created this repository: https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/v4 and many dependency I create depend on it, just to name a few:

https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/ra-ui

Looking at the `package.json`, the dependency is used here: https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/ra-ui/blob/master/package.json#L291

This happen only on that repo and we found it weird, because this repo can detect with the same kind of setting https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/bootstrap-styled it's usage without hassle.

What are the criteria? When will the `Used by` badge appear on that Github page?

Best!

Why is the badge not displayed and how can I make the badge appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation for this, but what I've observed is, whenever the dependency begins with an `@`, it comes up on the Dependency Graph of GitHub without a hyperlink to the repository, otherwise it comes up with a hyperlink to the repo.

If you see the dependencies in the [Dependency Graph](https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/ra-ui/network/dependencies) of the [ra-ui](https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/ra-ui) repo, you would notice that `@bootstrap-styled/v4` would come up without a hyperlink to the repo:

[image]

But other dependancies like below would come up with hyperlinks to their respective repos:

[image]

When the dependency comes up with a hyperlink to the repo in the Dependency Graph, the same is counted in the **Used by** feature of GitHub.

If you see the dependency `bootstrap-styled` is added too in the `ra-ui` repo, and the **Used by** feature in the [bootstrap-styled](https://github.com/bootstrap-styled/bootstrap-styled) repo is showing up fine.

So I believe the Dependency graph of GitHub is not getting a connection between the dependencies which begin with `@` and their respective repositories on GitHub and hence not counting them in the **Used by** feature.

**UPDATE:**

This issue has been fixed by GitHub and the **Used by** count is now showing up for repos having scoped packages

Comment: That's a shame, have you seen a issue tracker for the GitHub project itself? I'd like to report that but I don't know if that is already reported and if it can be reported.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa since GitHub source is not open, I don't think there is an open issue tracker available for GitHub. And I'm not sure how much of help it'd be by using the *Contact GitHub* option on the website.